# Can't theme an SvgPicture?

Tags: flutter, svg

I have a widget that receives children widgets that I want to color theme. I'm finding I can theme an `Icon` but have not found the theme for `SvgPicture` in the `flutter_svg` package. E.g., for my code below I get the unthemed SVG on the left and the themed Icon on the right. Is it possible to theme an SvgPicture? I've tried a bunch of color themes other than IconThemeData but haven't found the secret one yet. (Obviously I could use the `colorFilter` param of SvgPicture but I'd rather theme if possible.)

[image]

```
      Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
          iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          colorScheme: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.copyWith(
                primary: Colors.green,
              ),
        ),
        child: Builder(
          builder: (context) => Container(
            width: 40,
            height: 40,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6.0)),
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
            ),
            child: icon, // <- themes if Icon but not SvgPicture
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

### The reason:

The `ThemeData` class is part of Flutter's core material package. The constructor for `ThemeData` has properties for theming the various material components of a `MaterialApp`.

The `flutter_svg` package is a "Flutter Favorite" and is the defacto best option for SVGs in most cases, but it is a **Third Party** library. It is not a part of Flutter's core material package. So naturally there is no material `ThemeData` constructor property for theming a `SvgPicture` widget from the `flutter_svg` package.

### A solution:

To get around this issue the `flutter_svg` package has a [`DefaultSvgTheme`](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_svg/latest/flutter_svg/DefaultSvgTheme-class.html) widget, which defines *"The SVG theme to apply to descendant SvgPicture widgets which don't have explicit theme values."*.
If you put a `DefaultSvgTheme` widget at the root of your widget tree, you will effectively define the `SvgPicture` theme for the whole app.